# Unclear Error Reason - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, list, loops, file-handling, index-error

I am currently in the process of trying to write a Python script that will allow me to make usernames by using a list of surnames from a text file.

I have a text file with 100 surnames in it, each name on a separate line:

```
Gibbs
Dorsey
Delgado
Spears
Hull
King
Bailey
Wilcox
Meza
Barber
Greer
Bradley
Cannon
Boyle
Lawrence
Marks
Shelton
Hess
Anderson
Snow
Hale
Russo
Schmitt
Burch
Deleon
Terrell
Carr
Lamb
Sanford
West
Pruitt
Everett
Gardner
Graves
Rollins
Jarvis
Banks
Wagner
Pugh
Nguyen
Thompson
Bullock
Erickson
Cortez
Lambert
Zavala
Harmon
Mcdowell
Randolph
Nichols
Mcknight
Haley
Leach
Weaver
Nolan
Rocha
Walton
Reeves
Gill
Valentine
Lucero
Le
Hinton
Choi
Cowan
Robles
Reilly
Strong
Adams
Braun
Cooper
Padilla
Chaney
Heath
Saunders
Ramos
Blackwell
Blake
Mathews
Sherman
Byrd
Bauer
Bell
Sims
Berg
Austin
Watkins
Donovan
Huang
Cabrera
Giles
Cherry
Petersen
Massey
Farrell
Knox
Archer
Black
Stevens
Santos
```

For each surname, I would like the script to append it to a list/array.

Here is my script:

```
file = open(r"E:\Users\User\Documents\Python\Username Creator\Surnames.txt", "r")

# Counts the amount of lines in the script and assigns them to a variable
line_count = 0
for line in file:
    if line != "\n":
        line_count = line_count + 1
file.close()

file2 = open(r"E:\Users\User\Documents\Python\Username Creator\Surnames.txt", "r")

# For each line of the text file, the script should assign the surname to a list called 'info'
info = []
x = -1
for i in range(line_count):
    x = x + 1
    fileRead = file2.readlines()
    info.append(fileRead[x])
```

However, when I run the script, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Users\User\Documents\Python\Username Creator\Username Creator.py", line 17, in <module>
    info.append(fileRead[x])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have come across this error before, but this time, I don't know what I have written in the script that would cause it to show this error.

Does anyone have any ideas of how I could go about fixing this error?

Comment: Why are you using all those loops? Just do `info = file.readlines()`

Comment: The reason for the error is because you perform `fileRead = file2.readlines()` multiple times.  The first time through it loads fileRead with your 100 surnames but the second time through the file is already at the end so it resets fileRead to an empty list.  With that said, the answer provided by @BTables should sort things out for you.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little bit of a convoluted way to go about putting items from a file into a list. It can be done much simpler like this:

```
info = []
with open('file.txt') as f:
    info = [x.rstrip() for x in f]
```

For completeness sake, and to answer your original question, the error is produced because you call `readlines()` inside the loop. The first iteration will return all lines and every other call will return an empty list; thus, you cannot index into it with error.